# Question incorrectly closed , reason given: "rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete" not applicable

Tags: discussion

Would someone like to explain to me why [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/111708/1322) "CPUs for retro computer school project" was considered off-topic?

The reason given was "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete."

The OP was not looking for a specific product, he was looking for an architecture that was appropriate based on a set of criteria (external bus, > 50 MHz, serial interface).

Now his idea of retro is a little different than mine (I was thinking 6502, 600 etc.) but I guess a 25-year old architecture (MIPS) is enough retro for today's kids.  So I recommended the PIC32 ***family***.

Uh duh, I don't think the PIC32 is going to be "quickly obsolete" (in fact, Microchip just brought a whole new family, the PIC32MZ which I mentioned and the OP is considering when it becomes available).  So this whole thing about **"rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete" is nonsense** in relation to this question.  I think my answer could be very useful to someone else searching the site.

Now I admit, I did suggest, *as an example*, a specific PIC32 for him to look at, and where to buy it. If you want, I can take out my recommendation, and leave it more general.  But I don't see why that is necessary, because questions are closed based on the wording of the question, *not one of the answers*, am I right?  Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: p.s. I see the question has been reopened, but I'll leave my question here as I'd like to know why it was closed in the first place.

Comment: The question is rather "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" than a shopping question. It's not so much "I'm shopping for such and such" as rather "tell me what should go into a retro system (with some minimal constraints) and I will shop for that".

Answer (score 2):

The close reason reads:

> Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to
>   purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and
>   quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific
>   problem you're trying to solve.

No matter how you look at it, that question was asking for a recommendation for a specific product, and I disagree with it being reopened.

Comment: He was looking for a recommendation for a microcontroller family (Z80, PIC32 etc.) which are ***not specific*** products.  The PIC32MX250F128 is a ***specific*** product.  I don't know how it can be more clear than that, but I guess we will have to disagree.

Comment: I guess so, but it's still a shopping question.

Comment: I'll add http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112878/need-help-with-selecting-right-microcontroller-homemade-smart-watch as a similar question which could stay open, or at least wait for a community vote to close.